# Check if user is redirected or not in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a route in my symfony project that is restricted, so if I try to go there without being logged on I'm redirected to the login page.

I'd like to distinguish between when I try to go to a restricted area without being logged on, and when I just go to the login page directly.

Any clues of how to do this in symfony?

**Update**
By distinguish I mean some way to check if auser landed on the login page by going to that url directly, or if the user landed on the login page because he tried to access a restricted page.

Comment: +1 - I want to know that too

Comment: @Andeas - how you define that for visiting a page you need to be logged in?

Comment: @Andeas Distinguish how?

Comment: @imsiso: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html explains how to do that.

Comment: @hcoat: Updated the question. I don't know how to rephrase it in any other way.

Comment: @Andeas - thanks and now I think you can do it by customizing the url of the login page by adding something like `?1` at the end of it like `login?1` - please let me know if that was helpful.

Comment: That would probably also work @imsiso!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `$this->get('request')->headers->get('referer')` ?

`get('referer')` will only return an internal and relative path. If you are on `test.com` and click on a link going to your app `get('referer')` will return `null`. So if the user hits a redirect, the next request should have the proper URL.

Otherwise you could create a [custom exception listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and catch any `AccessDeniedException`. When the code catches one you could use the [FlashBag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) to pass values through the redirect.

Comment: +1 it seems more professional. what about my comment? adding something to login's like `login?1` address in the config and then checking it.

Comment: You could definitely use a query string instead of the flashbag

Comment: The 'referer' is always set for me, regardless of whether I'm visiting the login page directly or when I click on a restricted URL and get redirected to the login page because of it

Answer (score 6):

Thomas' solution is a good one. Here is an alternative.

Knowing that and you will only be redirected if not logged-in you can just have your security firewall redirect with an additional parameter.

security.yml

```
...
secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login/restricted
...
```

routing.yml

```
login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Default:login }

login:
    pattern:  /login/{restricted}
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Default:login }
```

controller

```
public function loginAction($restricted = null)
{
...
Do something with $restricted
...
```

Now if someone goes to the login page:

```
yoursite.com/login
```

everything will be normal and $restricted = null so you know they came directly.

If someone goes to:

```
yoursite.com/admin
```

when they are not logged-in they will be redirected to:

```
yoursite.com/login/restricted
```

In your controller `$restricted` will be set and you will know they tried to access a restricted area without authentication.

Of course you can change `restricted` to what ever would make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to hcoat answer, you can do this without creating new URL. You can use query parameter:

```
secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login?r
```

And then in your controller's action check for this parameter:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $redirected = $request->query->has('r');
    // ...
}
```